# First TH ignore resize column in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to ignore the resize column?

**Look at example image:**

[image: http://prntscr.com/a6h88u]

I want make a Table B from Table A.

But I don't know how.

Table CODE:

```
<table cellspacing='0' style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
                <tr>
                    <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/0.png" ></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/1.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/2.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/3.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/4.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img//ro/5.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/6.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/7.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/8.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/ro/9.png"></th>
                    <th><img src="stuff/img/hero.png"></th>
                </tr>

                <tr class="rowArrival">
                    <td><img src="stuff/img/tableLog_1.png"></td>
                    <td><span class="valueZero">0</span></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>111</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="rowDie">
                    <td><img src="stuff/img/tableLog_2.png"></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="row_2 rowSum">
                    <td><img src="stuff/img/tableLog_3.png"></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
```

I try to set `column width` but, it is not working.

Comment: If you are using only 1 column in the first row then you can use colspan property.

Comment: @Akash thank you for your replye, works nice,. If you want, you can add Answer and I Will accept it.

Comment: Ohk i will add it to the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<th colspan="12">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</th>
```

Here 12 is the number of columns in the table.

Note: It can be less than total number of columns as per your requirement.